# How to build a java object from multiple data sources when data is not available in all sources during the creation time?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've this design question that I'm trying to solve, and I hope to hear back from you, if you have any suggestions.

Let's say that we have a queue that you are listening to, the queue receives a message, the listener in your application grabs it, and builds an object, and pushes it to the cache, the object information at this moment has the data that it has received from the queue only, but it's still `waiting` on other data that's `not available` in `other data sources` (assume it's a DB) yet, what's the best approach to update the object when data becomes available in other data sources?

- Should I've a thread running in the background to fetch data periodically?
- I'm thinking of using decorator design pattern to build the object, Is that a good approach?
- Any suggestions are welcome.

**Update**: Some friends in the comments asked if I was complicating the question! And that's not the case, adding more details to explain why the case is not simple, imagine that you have a plan to drive from point A to point B, so you create a record for your trip, but there are some dependencies in order to fulfill this record, like you are waiting on a friend to confirm his pickup location, and you are waiting on your payment check to be received. The moment you receive the pickup location, you will update the record, later when you receive the payment, you will also go ahead and update it. Hope that explained the case in layman words.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the information that is not available?  Are you saying the object has two sources, and the queue is only one of them?

Comment: Your use case is unclear, and I am wondering if you are not over-complexifying your problem. Do you really need to instantiate the object without having all the data? Are you handling the cache manually?

Comment: If you can use apache camel, this can be achieved using `aggregator EIP`

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the data from the remaining sources, use an executor in conjunction with [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

If you are not familiar with futures, here are some tutorials:

1. https://www.baeldung.com/java-future
2. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/java-future.html

You can use a decorator design pattern, however this is generally done to extend the **functionality** of objects, not add data.

If these are primarily plain java objects (POJOs), only to store data, I would recommend to just add the data using settings when you get it from the other data source.

If there is a large amount of data, and it makes sense to divide it by data source, you can have one outer object with inner objects, each from a different source (builder pattern).

Comment: Your answer sounds doable, but how are you going to handle blocked threads? let's say that we have hundreds of messages waiting to be processed and each message has it's own Future, wouldn't that impact the application performance?

Comment: You can use an executor service to limit the number of available threads.  Ask another question if you want more information.